# How to uninstall LibreOffice on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: apt

I have Raspberry Pi 3 running Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

I'd like to uninstall all the crap I don't need, and among the first candidates is LibreOffice. However, when I try to uninstall LibreOffice, I'm warned that this would also uninstall `ubuntu-mate-desktop`:

`sudo apt-get remove libreoffice-calc`

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
    libreoffice-calc ubuntu-mate-desktop
```

I believe I do want to in fact keep `ubuntu-mate-desktop`.

I'm getting the same message when trying to remove other packages I don't need/want (e.g. `caja-wallpaper`).

Why is this?
How do I correctly uninstall LibreOffice (and other software/packages)?

Comment: As the text says, you cannot remove LibreOffice. Probably just a funny idea (or an error) introduced by the Mate package builder. Other OS´s with 'Mate Desktop' : LibreOffice isn't required. Examples Fedora, PCLinuxOS. - A theoretically solution : Repack the Mate package that says `Dependencies : libre-*` -

Comment: Uninstalling `ubuntu-mate-desktop` will not do any harm. It is a meta package.